# Simple Input in C (Input Redirection in Shell)

Tags: c, arrays, validation, input, matrix

I have an assignment in a beginner programming class that requires me to multiply matrices. The matrices are defined in a text file as follows:

```
4 5
1 5 3 2 6 
3 5 4 6 3
3 5 7 5 4
4 7 8 9 7
5 3
7 1 31
0 0 5
-5 -3 2
9 41 11
0 13 31
```

The first number is the rows, second is the column. Then the matrix is shown, and it repeats for the second. The program must input the data into two different two dimensional arrays, multiply them, then produce a result.

I understand how to do the multiplication but I am unsure of how to get this text from a file into an array, without using file streams. We must just direct the input to the program using standard input flow.
So it should be able to run as follows on a unix platform:

```
./matrix < input.txt
```

Should I use scanf? gets? fgets? I am a fairly fluent java programmer but completely new to C. Thanks!

Comment: Re: "without using file streams " : You *have* a stream for that redirected input, `stdin`. And cross `gets()` off that list right now. If the specific data **per-line** format must be enforced `fgets()` will likely be involved. Whether you use `sscanf()`, `strtok()`, `strtol`, or combinations therein are up to you after that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are handling numbers only, using `scanf` would work fine. Just use like you are taking input from user only. The problem arises when `gets` and `scanf` are used together by inexperienced users.

```
int row,col,matrix[maxrow][maxcol];
scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
for(int i = 0;i < row;i++)
{
    for(int j = 0;j < col;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&matrix[i][j);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not overly familiar with using C, could you provide an example of inputting the first section of my data into a two dimensional array? Thank you for your answer.  Edit: I would happily upvote but that requires 15 rep

Answer (score 0):

A simple example without check.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int row, int col, int m[row][col]){
    for(int r = 0; r < row ; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < col ; ++c){
            scanf("%d", &m[r][c]);
        }
    }
}

void print(int row, int col, int m[row][col]){
    for(int r = 0; r < row ; ++r){
        for(int c = 0; c < col ; ++c){
            printf("%d ", m[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int row1, col1;
    scanf("%d %d", &row1, &col1);
    int m1[row1][col1];
    input(row1, col1, m1);

    int row2, col2;
    scanf("%d %d", &row2, &col2);
    int m2[row2][col2];
    input(row2, col2, m2);

    //check print
    print(row1, col1, m1);
    print(row2, col2, m2);

    return 0;
}
```